# How to modify this code in Scala by using Brackets

Tags: scala, databricks

I have a spark dataframe in Databricks, with an ID and 200 other columns (like a pivot view of data). I would like to unpivot these data to make a tall object with half of the columns, where I'll end up with 100 rows per id. I'm using the Stack function and using specific column names.

Question is this: I'm new to scala and similar languages, and unfamiliar with best practices on how to use Brackets when literals are presented in multiple rows as below. Can I replace the Double quotes and + with something else?

```
%scala
val unPivotDF = hiveDF.select($"id", 
  expr("stack(100, " +
    "'cat1', cat1, " +
    "'cat2', cat2, " +
    "'cat3', cat3, " +
    //...
    "'cat99', cat99, " +
    "'cat100', cat100) as (Category,Value)")) 
  .where("Value is not null")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"""` to define multiline strings like:

```scala
"""
some string
over multiple lines
"""
```

In your case this will only work assuming that the string you're writing tolerates new lines.

---

Considering how repetitive it is, you could also generate the string with something like:

```scala
(1 to 100)
  .map(i => s"'cat$i', cat$i")
  .mkString(",")
```

*(To be adapted by the reader to exact needs)*

---

Edit: and to answer your initial question: brackets won't help in any way here.